Understanding a key definition in Lagarias Odlyzko's paper on Chebotarev density theorem
Lagarias & Odlyzko has a 1977 paper where they prove effective versions of the Chebotarev density theorem. I am having trouble understanding equation (3.1).
Here, $L/K$ is a Galois extension of number fields with Galois group $G$; $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$ dividing $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L$. The authors wrote:

For each irreducible character $\phi$ of $G$ we define
$$
 \phi_K\left(\mathfrak{p}^m\right)=\frac{1}{e} \sum_{\alpha \in I} \phi\left(\tau^m \alpha\right),\tag{3.1}
 $$
where $I$ is the inertia group of $\mathfrak{P}$, one of the prime ideal factors of $\mathfrak{p}, e=|I|$ and $\tau$ is one of the Frobenius automorphisms corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}$. If ${L}(s, \phi, L / K)$ is the Artin L-series associated to $\phi$, then for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$ we have
$$
 -\frac{{L}^{\prime}}{{L}}(s, \phi, L / K)=\sum_{\mathfrak{p}} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \phi_K\left(\mathfrak{p}^m\right) \log ({N} \mathfrak{p})({N} \mathfrak{p})^{-m s}\tag{3.2}
 $$
where the outer sum is over all the prime ideals of $K$. We should also note that the definitions (3.1) and (3.2) apply equally well to reducible characters.

First, I want to understand why (3.1) is well defined, i.e., independent of choice of $\mathfrak{P}$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ and of the Frobeinus element $\tau$. I know that the irreducible character $\phi$ is a class function. If $g\in G$, then $g\tau^mg^{-1}\alpha$ and $\tau^m\alpha$ are not necessarily conjugates, even after we sum over $\alpha\in I$. The issue would be resolved if we let $\tau$ be one of the Frobenius elements of $\mathfrak{P}$ (not $\mathfrak{p}$), where $\mathfrak{P}$ is the same as the prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$ defining the inertia group $I$. However, that's not what the author said.
Second, I want to understand why (3.2) is true. I know the definition of Artin L-functions: they are a product of certain characteristic polynomials associated to $\phi$, where the product is taken over all $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$. This means that one needs to calculate the logarithmic derivative of
$$
\frac{1}{\det(1-\tau_\mathfrak{P}(N\mathfrak{p})^{-s};V^{I_\mathfrak{P}})},
$$
where $V^{I_\mathfrak{P}}$ is the subspace of the representation fixed by $I_\mathfrak{P}$. I have no idea how this is related to the part $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \phi_K\left(\mathfrak{p}^m\right) \log ({N} \mathfrak{p})({N} \mathfrak{p})^{-m s}$ as written in (3.2).
Any help would be genuinely appreciated. I am fairly new to the theory of Hecke and Artin L-functions, so it would be great if you could point out explicitly what properties of these L-functions you're using. If you could also provide a few references to some explanatory materials, that would be fantastic. It doesn't have to contain all the proofs, I just need to know the statements.

For question 1, what exactly do you mean by Frobenius of $\frak{P}$ instead of $\frak{p}$? I also don't follow your point about $g\tau^m g^{-1} \alpha$ and $\tau^m \alpha$ not being conjugate. If you are considering another prime lying above $\frak{p}$, you would be considering a different/conjugate of the original ineritia group as well, so you would have $g\tau^m g^{-1} \cdot g \alpha g^{-1}$ instead of $g\tau^m g^{-1} \alpha$?

For 3.1 - as remarked in comment, I suspect the issue here is the expression $g\tau^m g^{-1} \alpha$ in your post. This suggests that as you change $\frak{P}$ lying above $\frak{p}$, perhaps the inertia group was not changed as well. If we fix this issue, the expression should be $g \tau^m g^{-1} \cdot g \alpha g^{-1} = g \tau^m a g^{-1}$, which is still conjugate to $\tau^m a$.
For 3.2, here is a sketch. To get an infinite series expansion for
$$det\left(1 - \phi(Frob_{\mathfrak{p}})N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s} \mid_{V^{I(\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p}})} \right)^{-1},$$
we upper triangularize the operator $Frob_{\mathfrak{p}} \mid_{V^{I(\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p})}}$; say its eigenvalues are $a_1, \cdots, a_k$. Then
$$det\left(1 - \phi(Frob_{\mathfrak{p}})N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s} \mid_{V^{I(\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p}})} \right)^{-1} = \prod_{i=1}^k (1 - a_i N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s})^{-1}.$$
Taking log derivative on both sides, you get
$$
\begin{align*}
= & \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{a_i N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s} \log N(\mathfrak{p})}{1 - a_i N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}} \\
= & \log N(\mathfrak{p}) \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{a_i N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}}{1 - a_i N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}} \\
= & \log N(\mathfrak{p}) \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(a_i N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}\right)^m
\end{align*}
$$
by expanding $\frac{1}{1-x}$ in geometric series. Switching the summations, we get the log derivative for local factor to be
$$= \log N(\mathfrak{p}) \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^m \right) N(\mathfrak{p})^{-ms}.$$
The main task now is to express for each $m$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^m$$
in terms of $\phi$ and $Frob_p$ themselves. Recall that $a_1, \cdots, a_k$ are the eigenvalues of $Frob_{\mathfrak{p}} \mid_{V^{I(\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p})}}$; clearly $a_1^m, \cdots, a_k^m$ are the eigenvalues of $Frob_{\mathfrak{p}}^m \mid_{V^{I(\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p})}}$, so this is really a question about computing trace of Frobenius and its powers.
This now boils down to the following result in representation theory.
Claim Suppose $D$ is a finite group acting on vector space $V$ over an algebraically closed field, and $I \vartriangleleft D$ is a normal subgroup. Let $g \in D$; $g$ naturally acts on $V^I$ as well. We have
$$tr\left(g \mid_{V^I} \right) = \frac{1}{|I|} \sum_{\alpha \in I} tr\left(g\alpha\right).$$
For your situation, it suffices to apply the claim $D = D(\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p})$, $I = I(\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p})$, and $g = Frob_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Quick sketch of proof of claim Since $I$ is normal, $V^I$ is also $G$-invariant. Thus decompose V as
$$V = V^I \oplus W$$
Hence
$$tr\left(g \mid_{V^I} \right) = tr(g) - tr\left(g \mid_{W} \right),$$
and thus for any $\alpha \in I$, we have
$$tr\left(g \mid_{V^I} \right) = tr\left(g \alpha \mid_{V^I} \right) = tr(g \alpha) - tr\left(g \alpha \mid_{W} \right),$$
Averaging over $\alpha \in I$, we see that
$$tr\left(g \mid_{V^I} \right) = \frac{1}{|I|} \sum_{\alpha \in I} tr(g \alpha) - \frac{1}{|I|} \sum_{\alpha \in I} tr\left(g \alpha \mid_{W} \right).$$
It suffices to show that
$$\sum_{\alpha \in I} tr\left(g \alpha \mid_{W} \right) = 0,$$
and this is because $\sum_{\alpha \in I} g \alpha$ maps $V$ to $V^I$, hence
$$\sum_{\alpha \in I} g \alpha \mid_{W} \equiv 0,$$
and so
$$\sum_{\alpha \in I} tr\left(g \alpha \mid_{W} \right) = tr \left(\sum_{\alpha \in I} g \alpha \mid_{W} \right) = 0.$$
As for a general reference of Artin $L$-functions, one good read is Noah Snyder's senior thesis "Artin's L-functions: A Historical Approach".

For question 1, by "Frobenius of $\mathfrak{P}$" I meant the element(s) in $D_\mathfrak{P}$ that is sent to the Frobenius generator under the isomorphism $D_\mathfrak{P}/I_\mathfrak{P}\to \operatorname{Gal}(\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P}\mid\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})$. The concern I have is that since $\tau$ is any Frobenius element of $\mathfrak{p}$, it is defined by first picking a prime $\mathfrak{P}$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$, but that $\mathfrak{P}$ may not be the same as the ideal $\mathfrak{P}'$ defining the inertia group $I$.

I see. I'm pretty sure the paper means frobenius of $\frak{P}$ then. So is any mention of frobenius in my answer
